# Performing a segue from a subview .xib to a view controller in the Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, subview

I have been sitting here for days trying to figure out how to transition from a subview that I created to a viewcontroller that is in the Main.storyboard.

The subview .xib is a sign up screen and I want it so when you press the sign up button it takes you from the subview the user is in to the main screen which is in the Main.storyboard.

The MenuViewController is what holds my subview .xib, they are in a scroll view, so how do I go from the subview of the scroll view to the other View Controller.

Here is what my screen looks like, I have no code for it yet because I have no idea of what to do 
This is the signUp screen:
https://gyazo.com/7551016222f281e51c12429584e55b82
When I click signUp I want it to bring me to ViewController:
https://gyazo.com/52b04186787d15d19f187adec22983f4

I know it's a lot but this is stopping me from advancing in this app, please help me.  Thank you!

Comment: You can't perform a segue between xib and storyboard. Use code to achieve what you want. Instantiate storyboard in your button action and push the root view controller.

Comment: How do I do all of that?